# Can Ruby be compiled and faster in the future?

Tags: ruby, performance, scalability

C, Java, C# and Python are compiled from the beginning. Thanks to Facebook, PHP is now also compilable and can be run on HHVM increasing performance of programs.
Ruby is not compilable and is slower than aforementioned languages. Is is possible that Ruby will be compilable in the future (like PHP with HHVM)? Or maybe there are some reasons it cannot be?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question encourages opinions and speculation, not specific answers. Please read "[help/on-topic]" for on-topic information and "[help/dont-ask]" for questions not to ask. Ruby could be compilable in the future but when and if is hazy.

Comment: All currently existing and even most past implementations of Ruby have compilers: YARV, Rubinius, JRuby, IronRuby, MagLev, Topaz, Cardinal, RubyGoLightly, XRuby, SmallRuby, BlueRuby, Alumina, Ruby.NET, the other IronRuby (there were two different implementations by the same name), RedSun, MacRuby, MRuby, RubyMotion, and probably tons of others I am forgetting. The only two implementations which never had compilers were IoRuby (which was never released) and MRI (which is deprecated and unmaintained). JRuby started out as a pure interpreter, but added a compiler later. More interestingly: …

Comment: … IronRuby started out as a pure *compiler* but added an interpreter later in order to *improve* performance! Of course, Ruby can be compiled. All languages can be compiled. Compilation and interpretation are traits of … well … the compiler or interpreter (duh!), not the language. Performance is a function of the amount of money/resources/people/PhD theses spent on making an implementation fast. Java started out dog-slow and only became fast when Java companies started buying Smalltalk and Lisp know-how. (Oracle HotSpot is still just a slightly modified Smalltalk VM at its core.)

Comment: Also, current CPU architectures and Operating Systems are actively hostile to languages like Ruby, when it comes to performance. But there are other architectures out there, which are a much better fit. The same applies to C: C is fast, because the current CPUs and OSs were explicitly designed to make C-ish languages run fast. On the original AS/400, for example, C is dog-slow, because the AS/400 doesn't have pointers, files, threads, processes, direct memory manipulation, or virtual memory, so C essentially has to run inside an interpreted emulator providing all those features.

Answer (score 2):

The question makes false statements/assumptions.

1. All of the language you mentioned (C, Java, C#, Python, *and* Ruby) are compiled. The difference is *when* they are compiled (runtime vs precompiled).
2. Ruby *can* be precompiled to bytecode as of 1.9
3. Ruby is not "slower" than the other language just because it is typically compiled at runtime (this is a major misconception). The code will startup faster if it is precompiled, but **precompiling the code will not make it run any faster**.